# how to write a loop in gnu make that feed list to execuable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have a lot of files that with .e extension, and I have a custom program that can process and convert them.

the custom program take input_file_name and output_file_name

`./custom [input] output`

It needs the [] around the input_file_name.

I used wildcard to get the name of all the .e files

`FILES = $(wildcard *.e)`

and I made it a phony target

```
.PHONY convert
convert:
  ./convert [$(FILES)] $(FILES).u
```

The issue that I have is that $(FILES) pass the whole list at once. For example, a.e b.e c.e. All the file's name are separated by one space.

```
a.e b.e c.e
```

I also tried foreach

```
$(foreach i, $(FILES), $(EXEC) [$(i)] $(basename .u))
```

It still feed the whole string to the program.

Please help.
How to only use gnu make build in function to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make is a declarative language, not an imperative language. You're describing what you want to be done, but what you should be doing is describing the end-state you want.

You want your `convert` target to produce all of the .u files. To do this, we can slightly adapt [an example](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) from the GNU make manual:

```
U_FILES := $(patsubst %.e,%.u,$(wildcard *.e))
```

Next, we tell make that running the `convert` target should produce all of the .u files:

```
.PHONY convert
convert: $(U_FILES)
```

Next, we teach make how to produce a .u file from a .e file. I like to use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) for this.

```
%.u: %.e
    ./custom [$<] $@
```

Structuring your Makefile like this gives you some advantages. For example, you can use `make -j` to run your Makefile in parallel.

Comment: You should definitely add single quotes around that argument, because `[]` is special to the shell: `'[$<]'`